# WCF self host: when I run into visual studio service works, when I run the release exe does not

Tags: wcf

I have a service that is host in a console application. when I run this application inside visual studio, the service is open and I can access from the client or when I use the uri in an internet browser.

However, when I run the exe, the service is not open and I can't acccess to the service. I have tried to run as elevated privileges, but it does not work.

Why in visual estudio works and stand alone not?

I am using VS2015 community and WCF 4.5.

Thanks.

Comment: Hope any permission problem... like Run as an admin?

Comment: May be that exe couldn't able to find the DLL path which you have installed through Nuget package. Have you checked that?